# Is there a way to automatically collapse specific columns for Responsive Layout Collapsed List?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm trying to use Tabulator to create a "Responsive Layout Collapsed List", per the example [here](http://tabulator.info/examples/4.7?#responsive-layout-collapse), and the documentation [here](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/layout#responsive-collapse).

The example's source code doesn't seem to match the example itself, but from my understanding and playing with code, as the width of the table is decreased and, as a result, columns are collapsed, tables are created for each row that contain the names and values for the columns that were collapsed as a result of the reduction in table width. In the case of the Tabulator example, it almost seems as if a particular width is being set on the table and that is forcing the columns to collapse because the extra columns don't fit that width, but I'd like to see if there is a better and more dynamic way to do this.

Is there a way to get the columns to **automatically** collapse? Meaning, a user won't have to manually reduce the width of the table to get the columns to collapse - the columns will already be collapsed on-load, with the ability to expand and collapse the collapsed list immediately with no further action needed from the user.

I've tried:

- Doing `table.hideColumn("column_name_here");` programmatically.
- Setting `visible: false` for each column that I wanted to automatically collapse.
- CSS `display: none` for each column that I wanted to automatically collapse.
- Manually setting the width CSS of the table to the point that the columns I wanted to collapse would do so without me having to adjust the table width after. This...worked, but it required too much guessing and fooling around for me to think it was the best and safest solution.
- `responsiveLayoutCollapseFormatter` (admittedly, I don't fully understand the example that was given for this one)

Just as an example, a teammate is using the Datatables library for the table on their website, and they were able to pass `className: 'none'` into the column objects of each of the columns that they wanted to automatically have collapsed on the page, and it indeed automatically collapses those columns into an expandable table of column names and values without the need to do anything else:

[Datatables Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7ANt.png)

From the example above, the "Message", "Aliases", "Type", "Queue", and "Skill" columns all have className: none in their column objects, while the rest of the columns don't; className: none causes those columns to automatically collapse, thus putting them into the collapsed table list without having to set a width manually or adjust the width manually on the page.

Is there an equivalent of this in Tabulator? I've been racking my brain trying to figure this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The point of the responsive collapse formatter it to collapse rows that no longer fit on the table as a result of its width being insufficient, it is there to enable responsive layouts on smaller screens sizes. There is not way to force it to collapse row early, as it collapses them based on available horizontal space on the table.

Thant being said it is very easy to mimic its effect on a table by using a ***rowFormatter*** if you just want to display some values under the columns

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    rowFormatter:function(row){
        //row - row component

        //define holder elements
        var listHolder = document.createElement("div");
        var list = document.createElement("table");

        //retrieve row data
        var data = row.getData();
        
        ///add each columns data to the list
        listContents += "<tr><td><strong>Name</strong></td><td>" + data.name + "</td></tr>";
        listContents += "<tr><td><strong>Age</strong></td><td>" + data.age + "</td></tr>";
        
        //add contents to list
        list.innerHTML = listContents;
        listHolder.appendChild(list);

       return listHolder;
    },
});
```

For more details on the row formatter have a look at the [Format Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/format#row)

You can use the ***rowFormatter*** to make extensive changes to the row layout, the [Row Formatter Example](http://tabulator.info/examples/4.7?#row-formatter) demonstrates an extreme case where you can replace the columns all together if needed

#### With Toggle Button

if you want a toggle button similar to the collapse formatter, then you need to do two thing, store a reference to the list element in the row data, and define a formatter to add to a toggle column.

```js
//define toggle formatter
var toggleFormatter = function(cell){
    var toggleEl = document.createElement("button"); // create your toggle button
    

    toggleEl.addEventListener("click", function(){
        var listHolder= cell.getData().listHolder; //lookup list element from row data
         listHolder.style.display = listHolder.style.display ? "none" : ""; //toggle the display property on the list element
    });
}

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    rowFormatter:function(row){
        //row - row component

        //define holder elements
        var listHolder = document.createElement("div");
        var data = row.getData();

        // CREATE TABLE AS PER ABOVE EXAMPLE
        
        // store the list element on the row data (without triggering an update)
        data.listHolder = listHolder;
 
       return listHolder;
    },
    columns:[
        //define toggle column
        {formatter:toggleFormatter, width:30, minWidth:30, hozAlign:"center", resizable:false, headerSort:false},
        //...other columns
    ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Oli. Is there any way to use your solution along with still having the ability to expand and collapse the rows for the column data list with the +/- button?

Comment: i have updated the answer with a toggle button approach, it just uses a plain button, but you can easily change this to be any element you like

Comment: I gave it a shot, but I think I am missing something. For your comment "// CREATE TABLE AS PER ABOVE EXAMPLE", what specific lines of codes need to go there in-place of that comment? I think that's throwing me off. I appreciate all your help.

Comment: It should be exactly the same code as the first row formatter example, you just want to add the `data.listHolder = listHolder` line before the return

Comment: Unfortunately, still a no-go. :( If you don't mind taking a look, here is a JS Fiddle I created. The overall table is successfully created, but no toggle buttons display and it doesn't seem like the child rows get created (sorry, had to make several edits for the fiddle): https://jsfiddle.net/ISeeTheCode/zpt6k21w/8/

Comment: Anything else you can think of, Oli? Let me know if my JS Fiddle is helpful - perhaps I'm still missing something or making a careless mistake.